# How to install cask for homebrew on mac

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, glew, homebrew-cask

I have set up git and homebrew, ran `brew reset-update`, `brew update` and `brew doctor` none of these give me errors but when I try to install glew using: `brew install glew` it gives me many errors:

```
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly30.11 MiB | 4.92 MiB/s
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Error: Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask     /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask` exited with 128.
```

I figured it was because cask wasn't installed(even though from what I've read it's supposed to install with homebrew) so tried to install cask separately too but it also gives me the same error as the bottom one, I've also tried reinstalling git and homebrew, updating everything as well as restarting my mac. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can install cask using this command.  Please note that this installs `cask`  which turns out to be unrelated to Homebrew casks as [@moribvndvs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64750/moribvndvs) pointed out:

```
$ brew install cask
```

For details, please see https://cask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/installation.html

Comment: This installs Cask (https://github.com/cask/cask) which is completely unrelated to Homebrew casks.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, [@moribvndvs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64750/moribvndvs)

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
brew tap homebrew/cask
```

which makes additional apps available for install. Then simply

```
brew install glew
```

would do.

Answer (score 2):

Homebrew Cask is implemented as part of Homebrew. All Homebrew Cask commands begin with brew

Please refer the link for more details
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/USAGE.md

Answer (score 2):

At the time of this writing, Cask is already installed as part of Homebrew on Macs. You just need to run:

```
homebrew <my-command> --cask
```

For reference, see [this thread on the deprecation](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/35645).